# Disable automatic DPI scaling

Tags: windows-10, high-dpi

I would like to disable the scaling that Windows automatically does to programs that don't support DPI scaling, which makes them blurry, without turning off scaling for programs that do support DPI scaling. I prefer the program to be small rather than blurry.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: You can disable scaling in an application’s compatibility options. I’m not aware of a way to only “half-enable” it globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, run the following command in an Administrator Command Prompt or PowerShell:

`setx __COMPAT_LAYER HighDpiAware /M`

It will make Windows treat all apps as high-DPI aware, except for apps that have some other compatibility settings manually set.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember having such an application, but you can try with the shortcut's properties:
"Compatibility / Change hi DPI settings"
[image: shortcut properties]